# Configuring server.xml jmsActivationSpec as part of MQ Light service on Bluemix

Tags: jakarta-ee, ibm-cloud, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty, mq

I have a liberty for Java application hosted on Bluemix using the MQ Light service. I would like to be able to set the 'Automatically stop endpoints on repeated message failure' parameter (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/SIBJMSActivationSpec_DetailForm.html).

I understand I should be able to do this in the server.xml file as part of the jmsActivationSpec tag, but cannot find any documentation specifying this. Is this possible, and what is the name of the parameter to set?

Comment: I have the same question for liberty and internal LIberty SIB . I'm curious to get the answer to this

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile doesn't have this capability.  You can open a Request For Enhancement at the following link:

[WebSphere RFE Community](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181)